# Agile-wise - what is the best way to change similar code (private class)

Tags: java, c#, agile

Looked at many topics about agile development, I am also huge fan of Clean Code but following code is giving me creeps. It looks like this:

Class A:

```
public class A{
    private B = new B();
}
```

Class B:

```
private class B{
    private ArrayStore aS;
    //other private fields

    private Constructor(){
        as = new ArrayStore();
        //initializing other private fields
    }

    private void someMethod(ObjectX obj){
        //some code
        aS.delete(obj);
    }
}
```

I need to add additional statement that `as.delete()` should be called only if something particular happens. Also didn't want to make `if` not to make code more difficult. The simpler is code - the better. So I thought about those solutions:

1. Since class B is violating open-close principle, I will make its fields and methods protected and override this method in new class then use it in class A.
2. I will set additional field within ObjectX class that will suggest when should it be deleted and when shouldn't then change class B method to call additional method (which will check objects properties then think about its deletion)

Any tips from you, guys? I mean I want to know what to do in situations like this when I want to override the code (which is private) and how to make it look appealing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Edi G. thank you very much for making the code look more appealing - your edit is appraciated! :)

Comment: You might be better off at [Code Review](codereview.stackexchange.com). There is also nothing agile about this. Agile is about organising your work, it does not say anything about coding style except the fact that the team should define their own rules (which could well be "don't care").

Comment: @nvoigt thanks for your advice, it seems I would've made better posting it there. Can I somehow move the question? Sorry for asking :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add additional statement that as.delete() should be called
>   only if something particular happens. Also didn't want to make if not
>   to make code more difficult. The simpler is code - the better.

I guess I don't agree that `if` makes the code too difficult and would go for the following approach:

```
private void someMethod(ObjectX obj){
    //some code
    if (aNameThatDescribesTheUseCaseWhenToDelete()) {
       aS.delete(obj);
    }
}

private boolean aNameThatDescribesTheUseCaseWhenToDelete() {
    // logic to figure out whether delete is okay or not
}
```

I think that's as KISSy as it gets.

If the logic to figure out when to delete gets too complex you can consider rules / predicates, but that's probably future stuff.

Comment: Thanks for answer jan! I too think that may be a good approach and is worth consideration. Still it has two problems: it changes existing implementation and adds a little bit of complexity by adding if (whether it's in function or creating a new one). Still it's probably very simple, which is nice :)